# Making a textbox comparison case-insensitive

Tags: c#, string-comparison, case-insensitive

Beginner here. I currently have a comparison with a textbox and a listbox, but I need the comparison to be case-insensitive. I keep seeing `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` but am unable to fit it into this line of code where I thought it belonged:

```
if (listBox1.Items[q].Equals(textBoxYourAnswer.Text))
{
    //stuff
}
```

Does it go here? Does it only work if the comparison text is in quotes, or will it work when the system is looking at a `listBox`?

Comment: you mean if (String.Compare(str1, str2, StringComparison.CurrentCulturrIgnoreCase) == 0)?

Comment: I... don't think so? I'm after the `.Equals` working but not being case sensitive with `textBoxYourAnswer.Text`. As a newbie, I can't tell if I mean what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listbox item is of type object, but the Equals overload that accepts a StringComparison argument is specific to the String type. If your listbox item is actually of type string, cast it to a string before calling Equals.

if(((string)listBox1.Items[q]).Equals(textBoxYourAnswer.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)

Comment: An excellent explanation followed by a perfect example. Thank you.